# How to replicate Ruby’s "each" method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make method `each` in Python like its in Ruby? Is that possible, am really do!

In Ruby its looks like:

```
%w[1 2 3 4].each { |i| puts i}
```

In Python we have `for`:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]: print(i)
```

So, I want to make `each` method in Python, here is my code:

```
class Iter:
    def each(self, data):
        processed = data.__iter__()
        yield processed.__next__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Iter()
    print(list(test.each([1, 2, 3])))
```

Its working not as `each`, its return only first element.
Thx in advance!

Comment: It only returns one element because you did `yield processed.__next__()` which only returns the first element of the iterator. Just return the iterator directly from `each`. `list` and most other constructs can use iterators since iterators *are* iterables like lists.

Comment: Also, you should really use `iter` and `next` instead of `.__iter__` and `.__next__` directly. In the end, this really just means that your `each` is an alias for `__iter__`. I would just properly implement the [iterator interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator) instead of using Ruby conventions. The two don't appear to be equivalent anyway since Ruby's version takes a function/block/whatever they're called.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, hmm, ok thats nice info, thx u friend

Comment: The reason you don't see this is a difference in philosophy. Ruby is an expression oriented language, so you can write a function (like `each`) that takes a block (which may be several lines long), and it looks very natural to call. Python's equivalent to Ruby's block is the `lambda` keyword, an anaemic one-line-only anonymous function. You can write `each` in Python (in fact, [I have done so](https://github.com/Mercerenies/alakazam/blob/master/alakazam/lift.py#L560-L567)). But it's just not as useful in a language where blocks are limited to one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Iter:
    def each(self, data):
        yield from data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Iter()
    for i in test.each([1, 2, 3]):
        print(i)
```

To implement the `each` method in python that is similar to Ruby, you can use the `yield` statement. If you use it inside a `for` it should work that way.

I'll also add the link to the documentation of yield statement [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#:%7E:text=The%20yield%20statement,-yield_stmt%20%3A%3A%3D%20yield_expression&text=Yield%20expressions%20and%20statements%20are,instead%20of%20a%20normal%20function.).

Comment: Thx for your answer! But, can I do it without `for` ?

Comment: @SonyMag They're using `for` to replace the `list` call you were using. They have roughly the same purpose: to pull elements from the iterator.